# When does Skulls of the Shogun save?

Tags: skulls-of-the-shogun

I downloaded Skulls of the Shogun yesterday and sat down and played it for about 5 or 10 minutes. I got possibly halfway through the first "level" before I had to quit the game.

As I had seen the game say several times "Saving Game" I thought - no problem, I'll just keep playing when I come back again, and shut it down.

When I tried to load the game this morning the level was restarted.

So, my question is: when does the game save really? Do I have to complete each level before it's completely saved?

It should be noted that I play on Xbox 360.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I need to look more closely. Instead of choosing continue campaign, I should have chosen the load game.

I guess it pays off to look at all choices.